# Custom f1_score metric in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, metrics

I want to implement the f1_score metric for tf.keras.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Accuracy, BinaryAccuracy
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class F1_Score(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

    def __init__(self, name='f1_score', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.f1 = self.add_weight(name='f1', initializer='zeros')

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        p = Precision(thresholds=0.5)(y_true, y_pred)
        r = Recall(thresholds=0.5)(y_true, y_pred)
        self.f1 = 2 * ((p * r) / (p + r + 1e-6))

    def result(self):
        return self.f1

    def reset_states(self):
        self.f1.assign(0)
        
model = Sequential([
  Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)),
  Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'),
])
x = np.random.normal(size=(10, 784))
y = np.random.choice(2, size=(10, 4))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(0.001), loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy', , F1_Score()])
model.fit(x[:1], y[:1], batch_size=1, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

I got an error:

> ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables
> on non-first call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get this error because you want to instantiate some `tf.Variable`s during the update_state function. When instantiate object from the class Precision and Recall, you are creating some `tf.Variable`s.

Instantiate the objects in the constructor, and call them in the update_state function:

```py
class F1_Score(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

    def __init__(self, name='f1_score', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.f1 = self.add_weight(name='f1', initializer='zeros')
        self.precision_fn = Precision(thresholds=0.5)
        self.recall_fn = Recall(thresholds=0.5)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        p = self.precision_fn(y_true, y_pred)
        r = self.recall_fn(y_true, y_pred)
        # since f1 is a variable, we use assign
        self.f1.assign(2 * ((p * r) / (p + r + 1e-6)))

    def result(self):
        return self.f1

    def reset_states(self):
        # we also need to reset the state of the precision and recall objects
        self.precision_fn.reset_states()
        self.recall_fn.reset_states()
        self.f1.assign(0)
```

---

**Explanation of the behavior :**

Tensorflow allow to create Variable only on the first call of a `tf.function`, see the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function) :

> tf.function only allows creating new tf.Variable objects when it is called for the first time

Keras metrics are wrapped in a tf.function to allow compatibility with tensorflow v1. You can find this comment in the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L81-L314)

> If `update_state` is not in eager/tf.function and it is not from a
> built-in metric, wrap it in `tf.function`. This is so that users writing
> custom metrics in v1 need not worry about control dependencies and
> return ops.

You also have another bug in your class, is that you override the `f1 tf.Variable` that you created with the calculation of your f1 score. To update the value of a variable, you need to use `assign`. And we must not forget to reset the states of the Precision and Recall Metrics objects in use!

Comment: I get an error `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign`
in  reset_states()!!

Comment: I also used `tf.compat.v1.assign` and got the same error

Comment: @BetterEnglish See my update. I missed some bugs in your code.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tensorflow-addons` which has a built-in method for F1-Score. (don't forget to `pip install tensorflow-addons`)

Have a look below:

```
  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001),
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),
                           tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=n_classes, average='macro'),
                           tfa.metrics.FBetaScore(beta=2.0, num_classes=n_classes, average='macro')])
```

If you do have a multi-label classification problem, you can change it to:

```
  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001),
                      loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
                      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(),
                               tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=1, average='macro',threshold=0.5),
                               tfa.metrics.FBetaScore(beta=2.0, num_classes=1, average='macro',threshold=0.5)])
```

Comment: BTW, have you tried using the built-in metrics to see how they work?

Comment: Those metrics work both for binary/multi-class/multi-label classification.

Comment: what is the difference between `tfa.metrics.F1Score` and `FBetaScore`?

Comment: F1 Score is a particular case of FBetaScore where Beta == 1.

Answer (score -2):

This is my code scoring f1 for Tensorflow 2.0:

```
class F1Score(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
  def __init__(self, name='F1Score', **kwargs):
    super(F1Score, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
    self.f1score = self.add_weight(name='F1Score', initializer='zeros')
    self.count = self.add_weight(name='F1ScoreCount', initializer='zeros')

  def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.bool)
    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.bool)

    true_positives = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, True), tf.equal(y_pred, True))
    true_positives = tf.cast(true_positives, self.dtype)
    count_true_positives = tf.reduce_sum(true_positives)

    possible_positives = tf.cast(y_true, self.dtype)
    count_possible_positives = tf.reduce_sum(possible_positives)

    predicted_positives = tf.cast(y_pred, self.dtype)
    count_predicted_positives = tf.reduce_sum(predicted_positives)

    precision = count_true_positives / (count_predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    recall = count_true_positives / (count_possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    f1_cal = 2*(precision*recall)/(precision + recall + K.epsilon())

    self.count.assign_add(1)
    a = 1.0 / self.count
    b = 1.0 - a
    self.f1score.assign(a*f1_cal+b*self.f1score)

  def result(self):
    return self.f1score
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)